# I cannot bundle install after installing rails in linux due to a problem with gem pg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg

I am trying to execute bundle install on a rails project, after installing rails and ruby following [this guide](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04), but I am getting the following message:

```
em files will remain installed in /home/home/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.1.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/home/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/pg-1.1.4/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (1.1.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.1.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  pg
```

And after executing:

```
gem install pg -v '1.1.4'
```

I get

```
   Building native extensions. This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing pg:
            ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/home/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.1.4/ext
/home/home/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/ruby -I /home/home/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20200816-25890-7twqf6.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/home/home/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-pg
        --without-pg
        --enable-windows-cross
        --disable-windows-cross
        --with-pg-config
        --without-pg-config
        --with-pg_config
        --without-pg_config
        --with-pg-dir
        --without-pg-dir
        --with-pg-include
        --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
        --with-pg-lib
        --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/home/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/pg-1.1.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/home/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.1.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/home/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/pg-1.1.4/gem_make.out
```

I have checked the file gem_make.out on vim and it seems to contain the same message copied above.

Comment: On ubuntu this is `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev` then try again.

Comment: I would like to add on Ben Trewern's answer,
 `sudo apt-get install postgresql-client libpq5 libpq-dev`
then do
 `gem install pg`

Comment: Yes, all those answers worked. Thank you.